# RegForm couldn't send user to sucess page after Registration in .Tpl file

Tags: javascript, php, task-parallel-library

A group want me to work on a registration page on there site run in PHP (HYIP).Complain that users are not redirected to success page after they click the signup button.but when I asked him to send me the source he has given me *.tpl files and i was expecting a *.php file.......i need to fix this now but don't really know where or how to spot the error..

here is the full code in signup.tpl

**HTML**

```
<form method=post onsubmit="return checkform()" name="regform">
<input type=hidden name=a value="signup">
<input type=hidden name=action value="signup">
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0>
<tr>
 <td>Your Full Name:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=fullname value="{$frm.fullname|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>.......<td><input type=submit value="Register" class=sbmt></td>
</tr></table>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script language=javascript>
 function checkform() {
  if (document.regform.fullname.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your full name!");
    document.regform.fullname.focus();
    return false;
  }
 {/literal}
 {if $settings.use_user_location == 1}
 {literal}
  if (document.regform.address.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your address!");
    document.regform.address.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.city.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your city!");
    document.regform.city.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.country.options[document.regform.country.selectedIndex].text == '--SELECT--') {
    alert("Please choose your country!");
    document.regform.country.focus();
    return false;
  }
 {/literal}
 {/if}
 {literal}
  if (document.regform.username.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your username!");
    document.regform.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (!document.regform.username.value.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+$/)) {
    alert("For username you should use English letters and digits only!");
    document.regform.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.password.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your password!");
    document.regform.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.password.value != document.regform.password2.value) {
    alert("Please check your password!");
    document.regform.password2.focus();
    return false;
  }
 {/literal}
 {if $settings.use_transaction_code}
 {literal}
  if (document.regform.transaction_code.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your transaction code!");
    document.regform.transaction_code.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.transaction_code.value != document.regform.transaction_code2.value) {
    alert("Please check your transaction code!");
    document.regform.transaction_code2.focus();
    return false;
  }
 {/literal}
 {/if}
 {literal}
  if (document.regform.email.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your e-mail address!");
    document.regform.email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.email.value != document.regform.email1.value) {
    alert("Please retupe your e-mail!");
    document.regform.email.focus();
    return false;
  }


























  if (document.regform.agree.checked == false) {
    alert("You have to agree with the Terms and Conditions!");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

 function IsNumeric(sText) {
  var ValidChars = "0123456789";
  var IsNumber=true;
  var Char;
  if (sText == '') return false;
  for (i = 0; i < sText.length && IsNumber == true; i++) { 
    Char = sText.charAt(i); 
    if (ValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1) {
      IsNumber = false;
    }
  }
  return IsNumber;
 }
 </script>
```

**full page code here**

```
<section class="wrapper">
            <div class="main_content">
                <div class="container">
<h3>Register Account</h3>
<div class="separate"><span></span></div>
{if $deny_registration}
 We are closed for new registrations now.
{elseif $settings.use_referal_program && $settings.force_upline && !$referer && !$settings.get_rand_ref}
 You  do not have a upline. Our system require a upline for each user.
{else}
 {literal}

 <script language=javascript>
 function checkform() {
  if (document.regform.fullname.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your full name!");
    document.regform.fullname.focus();
    return false;
  }
 {/literal}
 {if $settings.use_user_location == 1}
 {literal}
  if (document.regform.address.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your address!");
    document.regform.address.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.city.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your city!");
    document.regform.city.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.country.options[document.regform.country.selectedIndex].text == '--SELECT--') {
    alert("Please choose your country!");
    document.regform.country.focus();
    return false;
  }
 {/literal}
 {/if}
 {literal}
  if (document.regform.username.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your username!");
    document.regform.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (!document.regform.username.value.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+$/)) {
    alert("For username you should use English letters and digits only!");
    document.regform.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.password.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your password!");
    document.regform.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.password.value != document.regform.password2.value) {
    alert("Please check your password!");
    document.regform.password2.focus();
    return false;
  }
 {/literal}
 {if $settings.use_transaction_code}
 {literal}
  if (document.regform.transaction_code.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your transaction code!");
    document.regform.transaction_code.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.transaction_code.value != document.regform.transaction_code2.value) {
    alert("Please check your transaction code!");
    document.regform.transaction_code2.focus();
    return false;
  }
 {/literal}
 {/if}
 {literal}
  if (document.regform.email.value == '') {
    alert("Please enter your e-mail address!");
    document.regform.email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.email.value != document.regform.email1.value) {
    alert("Please retupe your e-mail!");
    document.regform.email.focus();
    return false;
  }


























  if (document.regform.agree.checked == false) {
    alert("You have to agree with the Terms and Conditions!");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

 function IsNumeric(sText) {
  var ValidChars = "0123456789";
  var IsNumber=true;
  var Char;
  if (sText == '') return false;
  for (i = 0; i < sText.length && IsNumber == true; i++) { 
    Char = sText.charAt(i); 
    if (ValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1) {
      IsNumber = false;
    }
  }
  return IsNumber;
 }
 </script>
 {/literal}

 {if $errors}
  <ul style="color:red">
  {section name=e loop=$errors} 
   {if $errors[e] eq 'full_name'}
    <li>Please enter your full name!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'address'}
    <li>Please enter your address!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'city'}
    <li>Please enter your city!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'state'}
    <li>Please enter your state!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'zip'}
    <li>Please enter your zip!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'country'}
    <li>Please choose your country!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'username'}
    <li>Please enter valid username! It should contains English letters and digits only.
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'username_exists'}
    <li>Sorry, such user already exists! Please try another username. 
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'email_exists'}
    <li>Sorry, such email already exists! Please try another email. 
   {/if} 
   {if $errors[e] eq 'password'} 
    <li>Please enter a password!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'password_confirm'}
    <li>Please check your password!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'password_too_small'}
    <li>The password you provided is too small, please enter at least {$settings.min_user_password_length} characters!
   {/if} 
   {if $errors[e] eq 'transaction_code'} 
    <li>Please enter the Transaction Code!
   {/if} 
   {if $errors[e] eq 'transaction_code_confirm'} 
    <li>Please check your Transaction Code!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'transaction_code_too_small'}
    <li>The Transaction Code you provided is too small, please enter at least {$settings.min_user_password_length} characters!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'transaction_code_vs_password'} 
    <li>The Transaction Code should differ from the Password!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'egold'} 
    <li>Please enter your e-gold account number!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'invalid_perfectmoney_account'} 
    <li>Please enter USD PerfectMoney account number!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'email'} 
    <li>Please enter your e-mail!
   {/if}



   {if $errors[e] eq 'agree'}
    <li>You have to agree with the Terms and Conditions!
   {/if}
   {if $errors[e] eq 'turing_image'}
    <li>Enter the verification code as it is shown in the corresponding box.
   {/if} 
   {if $errors[e] eq 'no_upline'}
    <li>The system requires an upline to register. {if $settings.get_rand_ref}You have to be agreed to random one or found a referral link in the net.{/if}
   {/if} 
   {if $errors[e] eq 'ip_exists_in_database'}
    <li>Your IP already exists in our database. Sorry, but registration impossible.
   {/if}







   <br> 
  {/section}
  </ul>
 {/if} 
<form method=post onsubmit="return checkform()" name="regform">
<input type=hidden name=a value="signup">
<input type=hidden name=action value="signup">
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=0>
<tr>
 <td>Your Full Name:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=fullname value="{$frm.fullname|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
{if $settings.use_user_location}
<tr>
 <td>Your City:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=city value="{$frm.city|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
 <td>Your Country:</td>
 <td>
  <select name='country' class=inpts>
<option value=''>--SELECT--</option>
{section name=c loop=$countries}
<option {if $countries[c].name eq $frm.country}selected{/if}>{$countries[c].name|escape:"quotes"}</option>
{/section}
  </td>
</tr>
{/if}
<tr>
 <td>Your Username:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=username value="{$frm.username|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Define Password:</td>
 <td><input type=password name=password value="{$frm.password|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>Retype Password:</td>
 <td><input type=password name=password2 value="{$frm.password2|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
{if $settings.use_transaction_code}
<tr>
 <td>Define Transaction Code:</td>
 <td><input type=password name=transaction_code value="{$frm.transaction_code|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr><tr>
 <td>Retype Transaction Code:</td>
 <td><input type=password name=transaction_code2 value="{$frm.transaction_code2|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
{/if}
{foreach from=$pay_accounts item=ps}
<tr>
 <td>Your {$ps.name} Account:</td>
 <td><input type=text class=inpts size=30 name=pay_account[{$ps.id}] value="{$ps.account|escape:html}" data-validate="{$ps.validate.func}" data-validate-{$ps.validate.func}="{$ps.validate[$ps.validate.func]}" data-validate-notice="{$ps.validate.notification|escape:html}" placeholder="{$ps.validate.placeholder|escape:html}"></td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
{foreach item=p from=$mpay_accounts}
{foreach item=ps from=$p.accounts}
<tr>
 <td>Your {$p.name} {$ps.name}:</td>
 <td><input type=text class=inpts size=30 name="pay_account[{$p.id}][{$ps.name|escape:html}]" value="{$ps.value|escape:html}"></td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
{/foreach}
<tr>
 <td>Your E-mail Address:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=email value="{$frm.email|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Retype Your E-mail:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=email1 value="{$frm.email1|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Secret question:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=sq value="{$frm.sq|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Secret answer:</td>
 <td><input type=text name=sa value="{$frm.sa|escape:"quotes"}" class=inpts size=30></td>
</tr>

{if $settings.use_referal_program}
{if $referer}
<tr>
 <td>Your Upline:</td>
 <td>{*<a href="mailto:{$referer.email}">*}{$referer.name}{*</a>*} ({$referer.username})</td>
</tr>
{else}
{if $settings.force_upline}
 {if $settings.get_rand_ref}
  <tr>
   <td colspan=2>
    You do not have an upline. Our system requires an upline for each user. You'll have to agree to get a random one or find a referral link on the net.
    <input type=checkbox name="rand_ref" value=1>
   </td>
  </tr>
 {else}
  <tr>
   <td colspan=2>
    You do not have an upline. Our system requires an upline for each user.
   </td>
  </tr>
 {/if}
{/if}
{/if}
{/if}


<tr>
 <td colspan=2><input type=checkbox name=agree value=1 {if $frm.agree}checked{/if} > I agree with <a href="{"?a=rules"|encurl}">Terms and conditions</a></td>
</tr>
{if $ti.check.signup}
<tr>
 <td class=menutxt align=right><img src="{"?a=show_validation_image&`$ti.session.name`=`$ti.session.id`&rand=`$ti.session.rand`"|encurl}"></td>
 <td><input type=text name=validation_number class=inpts size=15></td>
</tr>
{/if}
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><input type=submit value="Register" class=sbmt></td>
</tr></table>
</form>
{/if}
                </div>
            </div>
                    </section>
```

Comment: it'll help to know what *does* happen...

Comment: @LeroyStav , what will ?

Comment: in order to help you it would help to know what *does* happen when the submit button is clicked... at a glance the code looks fine

Comment: @LeroyStav   404 error not found is the error

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to put in the correct `action` into the form, or this is a backend problem of the framework, telling the front end to redirect to a page that doesn't exist.  At a glance your code seems fine, and clearly it submits the form as, well, hitting the button does try to take you *somewhere*.  Just saying "404 not found" isn't quite enough as you aren't telling us *what file is giving you a 404*, but based on what I'm seeing thats the best I can do for you at the moment

Comment: there is no action in the form,and i just added it now but its still does same thing it redirect me to a page **https://mysite.co/signup/say/done** and i cant find this page in the **signup.tpl** file either

Comment: I'm telling you this is a back-end problem, nothing to do with the tpl file they sent you.  Either you need to be told the correct action or they need to fix the endpoint